# Convert irregular time series to regular for running bfast model

Tags: r, ndvi, time-series

I have NDVI rasters extracted from Sentinel-2 with irregular time series over a year and missing data of July. I would like to generate the irregular time series to a monthly regular time series in R and I am stuck in this step. My data and my script is below:

```
setwd("P:/Mosaic")
listsen2 =list.files(pattern = ".tif$", all.files=TRUE,full.names = FALSE) 
sen2=stack(listsen2) # Create a raster stack from the .tif files
listsen2_dates =  substr(basename(listsen2), 1, 8) # Extract dates from file names
listsen2_dates <- as.Date(listsen2_dates, "%Y%m%d") # Convert dates to Date objects
names(sen2) <- listsen2_dates # Assign the extracted dates as layer names to the raster stack
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: So you have a non-equidistant time series of raster data with some data missing in July... What is even the point of making a monthly equidistant time series? But you would  need to consider aggregations on the one hand (Jan 10, Jan 20, ...) and gap filling on the other hand. However, I can't imagine that you'll get some valid interpolation here when your original images are missing (but I am happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: @dimfalk. Thank for your suggestion. Based on your suggestion, I will ask extra question about how to fill the missing data.